# How to convert a Future String to an image URL in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I can't get the image URL from Firestore, it's always returning Instance of Future String.

Here is my code:

```
class Animal_Data_Stream extends StatelessWidget {
  User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();
  var url;


  Future<String> getImg(String s) async {
    final ref =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('animal_image/').child(s);
    String abc = "abc";
    try{
      abc = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      print(abc);
      return abc;
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e);
      return "null";
    }
  }




  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc("LQ0PFtnsaxXU1c4tY0ZM")
        .collection("Visitor")
        .doc(user!.uid)
        .collection("animals")
        .snapshots(),
        builder:
        (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot){
          List <Widget> Data = [];
          var image_2;
          final animal_data = streamSnapshot.data?.docs;
          return
          animal_data?.length !=0?
          Column(
            children: [
              for( var data in animal_data!) kCard(context ,  getImg(data["animal_image"]) , data["animal_name"],
              data["animal_kingdom"] , data["animal_class"] , getImg(data["animal_image"]).toString() ,data["animal_species"] )

            ]
          ):
          Column();
    });
  }
}



  );
}
```

I tried many times but couldn't get the desired result. What can I try next?

Answer (score 1):

You have to think about **data structure** that you are providing to your `UI` part because for now, you have to make additional `async` operations to retrieve it.

But for your current example is only on the choice to use `FutureBuilder` inside of `StreamBuilder` like in example below:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("users")
            .doc("LQ0PFtnsaxXU1c4tY0ZM")
            .collection("Visitor")
            .doc(user!.uid)
            .collection("animals")
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> streamSnapshot) {
          List<Widget> Data = [];
          var image_2;
          final animal_data = streamSnapshot.data?.docs;
          return animal_data?.length != 0
              ? Column(children: [
                  for (var data in animal_data!)
                    FutureBuilder<String>(
                        future: getImg(data["animal_image"]),
                        builder: (_, imageSnapshot) {
                          final imageUrl = imageSnapshot.data;
                          return imageUrl != null
                              ? kCard(
                                  context,
                                  imageUrl,
                                  data["animal_name"],
                                  data["animal_kingdom"],
                                  data["animal_class"],
                                  imageUrl.toString(),
                                  data["animal_species"])
                              : const SizedBox.shrink();
                        })
                ])
              : Column();
        });
  }
```